# Struct in Struct with vectors Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, struct

I have two structs ITEM and TABLE, one of which contains the other one, i.e. TABLE contains many ITEMS. I use this code to create the structs and the table and items with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct ITEM {
 std::string itemTitle;
};

struct TABLE {
 std::string tableName;
 int num;
 ITEM* items;
};

TABLE setTABLE(std::string, int num) {
 struct ITEM* item = (struct ITEM*) malloc(sizeof(struct ITEM) * num);
 TABLE table = {tableName, num, item};
 return table;
}

int main() {
 std::vector<TABLE> tables;
 tables.push_back(setTABLE("TEST", 3));
 tables[0].items[0].itemTitle = "TestItem";
 std::cout << tables[0].items[0].itemTitle << "\n";

 return 0;
}
```

I want to set the itemTitle of the ITEM at position 0, but when I cout the result i get

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I guess the malloc is not sufficient to this? Or is my code construction misconstrued in the first place? What I wanted to achieve is build a custom table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc()` allocates memory, whereas [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) allocates memory *and* initializes (invoking a constructor of an object for example). As `malloc()` is being used `items` is a pointer to allocated but uninitialized memory which is accessed at:

```
tables[0].items[0].itemTitle = "TestItem";
```

causing the segmentation fault. But, don't use `new` just use a `std::vector<ITEM>` instead. An initial size is not required but can be supplied if required and the `vector` constructed with `n` default elements:

```
struct Table
{
    Table(std::string const& aName, const size_t a_num) :
        tableName(aName), items(a_num) {}
    std::string tableName;
    std::vector<Item> items;
};
```

Note `num` no longer required as `items.size()` can be used and don't use all uppercase as these are generally used for macros.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning variable `table` which is created on the stack -- you will need to `malloc` memory for `table` first